# Can anyone figure out my problem [Python]

Tags: python

I have been trying to debug the below python cgi code but doesn't seems to work. When i try in new file it these three lines seems to work

```
filename=unique_file('C:/wamp/www/project/input.fasta')
prefix, suffix = os.path.splitext(filename)
fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix, prefix+"_", dirname)
```

But, when i try like this way then i get error unique_file is not define >>>

```
form=cgi.FieldStorage()
i=(form["dfile"].value)
j=(form["sequence"].value)
if (i!="" and j=="" ):
    filename=(form["dfile"].filename)
    (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(filename)
    alignfile=name + '.aln'
elif(j!="" and i==""):
    filename=unique_file('C:/wamp/www/project/input.fasta')
    prefix, suffix = os.path.splitext(filename)
    fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix, prefix+"_", dirname)
    file = open(filename, 'w')
    value=str(j)
    file.write(value)
    file.close()
    (name, ext) = os.path.splitext(filename)
    alignfile=name + '.aln'
```

What i am trying to do is check two options from form:- Fileupload and textarea. If fileupload is true then there is nothing to do except separating file and its extension. But when textarea is true then i have to generate unique file name and write content in it and pass filename and its extension.

Error i got is...

```
type 'exceptions.NameError'>: name 'unique_file' is not defined
  args = ("name 'unique_file' is not defined",)
  message = "name 'unique_file' is not defined"
```

Any suggestions and corrections are appreciated

Thanks for your concern

Comment: If you put four spaces before each line of code then it'll format better.

Comment: unique_file is not defined. How is this error hard to understand?

Comment: @user: you're making it really hard to help you. Is this how your code actually looks like in your file?

Comment: what is it with all this brackets? my eyes burn.

Comment: 3. The formatting is not "wrong", *per se*, but could be much improved. I recommend reading (and adhering to) PEP 8, Style Guide for Python Code [http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/]

Comment: 1. Where is the `unique_file` function defined in your codebase? `grep` should help you if you didn't write the code yourself (it doesn't match the signature of `unique_file` in `SciPy`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either import or define your `unique_file` method before using it.

They will look something like:

```
from mymodule import unique_file
```

or:

```
def unique_file():
    # return a unique file
```

Comment: But, i was wondering why above three lines of codes work without defining unique_file function or import module

Comment: @user: they don't. if that's the actual content of your file, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

unique_file() isn't a built-in function of Python. So I assume, either you forget a line in your first code snippet which actually imports this function, or you configured your python interpreter to load a startup file (http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONSTARTUP).  In the second case, the CGI script can't find this function because it runs with the web server identity which probably lacks the PYTHONSTARTUP env. variable definition.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when a compiler or interpreter says something isn't defined, that's precisely what the problem is. So, you have to answer the question "why is it not defined?". Have you actually defined a method named "unique_file"? If so, maybe the name is misspelled, or maybe it's not defined before this code is executed.

If the function is in another file or module, have you imported that module to gain access to the function?

When you say it works in one way but not the other, what's the difference? Does one method auto-import some functions that the other does not?

Since unique_file is not a built-in command, you're probably forgetting to actually define a function with that name, or forgetting to import it from an existing module.